# How long after MC send an Individual Email Result record (in Sales Cloud) is created?

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, sales-cloud, email-tracking

An email was sent using Journey. Please advice me how long does it take to see Triggered Send and Individual Email Result record in the SC?
Does Salesforce have any official metrics here?

Thank you in an advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take the effort to do some research and check the salesforce documentation, which states this pretty precisely.

[Tracking results are typically synced within one hour](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_email_send_record.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null). 
There's a bit more to this in the documentation but I leave the rest of the research to you. :)